# Vector field proof

Tags: calculus

We are given:
$(\nabla \times A)_i=\sum_{j,k=1}^{3}\epsilon_{ijk}$$\frac{\partial A_k} {\partial r_j}$ (1)
and $\nabla\times(\nabla\times A)=\nabla(\nabla\cdot\ A)-{\nabla}^2 A$ (2)

Show: $\nabla\times(\nabla\times(\nabla\times A))=-{\nabla}^2(\nabla\times A)$

Firstly I put (2) into the left hand side to get:

$\nabla\times(\nabla(\nabla\cdot\ A)-{\nabla}^2 A)$, then taking the whole equation over i, we get:

$\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_j\partial_k\partial_l A_l-\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_j\partial_k\partial_k A_l$ which I do not know how to simplify further.

Also, I have tried using (1) and getting:

$\nabla\times(\nabla\times(\nabla\times A))=\sum_{j,k=1}^{3}\epsilon_{ijk}$$\frac{\partial (\nabla\times(\nabla\times A))_k} {\partial r_j}$

but I don't know how to differentiate this, or to proceed to the result looking the same as the right hand side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand from outside,
$$\begin{align}\nabla\times(\nabla\times(\nabla\times A))=&\nabla(\nabla\cdot (\nabla\times A))-\nabla^2(\nabla\times A)\end{align}$$
and note that
$$\nabla\cdot(\nabla\times A)=\partial_i(\epsilon^{ijk}\partial_jA_k)=\epsilon^{ijk}(\partial_i\partial_j A_k)=0$$

Comment: Thanks, totally get it now, very helpful.

Comment: @Dansmith You're welcome. As a gentle suggestion, the answer which solves your question is better to be marked as accept by clicking "check", claiming the question has been solved. :)